# Python Stack (Valid Parentheses)

Tags: python, stack

Given a string s containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', determine if the input string is valid.

An input string is valid if:

Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.

EDIT: Updated code as follows:

```
class Solution:
    def isValid(self, s: str) -> bool:
        stack = []
        if len(s)<2:
            return False
        for ch in s:
            if ch == "(" or ch == "{" or ch == "[":
                stack.append(ch)
            elif ch == ")":
                if not stack or stack.pop() != "(":
                    return False
                
            elif ch == "]":
                if not stack or stack.pop() != "[":
                    return False
                
            elif ch == "}":
                if not stack == True or stack.pop() != "{":
                    return False
                
        
        return True
```

What I am trying to do is to create a stack. So any opening brackets are appended inside. When the program sees a closing bracket, it has to match the type. If it does, it pops off the bracket and continues the loop. However, I got this error:

```
IndexError: pop from empty list
    stack.pop()
Line 13 in isValid (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().isValid(param_1)
Line 48 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 59 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Not sure what's the error here, any help will be appreciated.
Input is "()[]{}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are popping twice for each character that is not an opening parenthesis: once in the `if` condition, and then again `else`. For example, for input of `"()"`:

- 0th character: `"("` gets pushed on the stack. Stack has 1 elements.
- 1th character: `"("` is popped from the stack. Stack has 0 elements. `"("` is same as `"("`, and so `else` is executed. `stack.pop()` raises the shown exception.

In fact, if the parenthesis matches, nothing else needs to be done. Just delete the `else: stack.pop()` clauses.

As an aside, you also need to ensure, if the character is not an opening parenthesis, that the stack is not empty, and `return False` if so, to account for examples like `")"` or `"[{}()]]"`, otherwise `stack.pop()` will again fail when they encounter the unmatched closing parenthesis.

As a second aside, `if s[i] == ("(" or "{" or "["):` does not do what you think. `"("` is truthy, as is `"{"`; `X or Y` returns the second element in case the first element is truthy, and is left-associative. Thus, the result of `"(" or "{" or "["` is `"["`, which is truthy, so this `if` is equivalent to `if s[i] == "["`. You want to write one of these instead:

```
if s[i] == "(" or s[i] == "{" or s[i] == "[":
if s[i] in ["(", "{", "["]:
if s[i] in {"(", "{", "["}:
if s[i] in "({[":
```

and after that, `if not stack: return False` to address the previous point.

Third aside: `range(start, end)` starts at `start` and finished *before* `end`, so to iterate over indices of all characters in a string, you need `range(0, len(s))`. E.g. if the string is `"([])"`, then `range(0, len(s)-1)` is `range(0, 3)`, which will produce indices `0`, `1` and `2` — so the last character, `s[3]`, will never be inspected. Thus, `-1` there is harmful, and should be removed. Or, better than that, since you never use the index except to access the character at that index, it would be better to skip the index idea altogether, and iterate the characters directly: `for ch in s:`

And a minor aside: all the closing parenthesis checks are mutually exclusive, so using `elif` insted of the 2nd and 3rd `if` would make it slightly more performant. You could also collapse all of the cases into one if you have a lookup dict telling you which opening parenthesis corresponds to each closing one.

Comment: Hi there. Understood your first point. For the second point,  I've added if not stack or s[i] == ")": ....
However, when this input is given:
"()[]{}"

my program now returns false instead of true.

Comment: You're right, I thought that would be invalid, but upon rereading the task spec, it should be valid. I corrected the answer to address that. However, in that case, shouldn't `""` also be valid? After all, all of the opening parentheses are matched, and in the correct order...

Comment: Thank you for the advice and suggestions thus far. Unfortunately, the wrong answer is still being produced (false instead of true). Edited my code for clarification

Comment: Not `elif ch == ")": if not stack or stack.pop() != "(":`. You need to write `elif not stack: return False` followed by `elif ch == ")": if stack.pop() != "(": return False`. (Also, `stack == True` will never be truthy in your code.)

Comment: Why am I unable to put the empty stack check after checking for the symbol though? If I'm checking directly for the empty stack first, I do understand it works. But why won't my case work?

Comment: Actually, never mind, I misread what you wrote. Your code seems fine, except for that last `not stack == True` bit. It has to be just `not stack` (or `stack == []`, or `len(stack) == 0`). Your code parses as `not (stack == True)`.